How to specify base-path in specmatic test
We have a use case in which the base-paths are defined in the servers attribute.
 
specmatic.json
{ "sources": [ { "provider" : "filesystem", "test" : [ "pets.yaml", "products.yaml" ] } ] } 
Example yaml files : products.yaml, pets.yaml
To run the test on a single yaml, I provide the base-path in --testBaseUrl parameter itself. However, when the specmatic.json has multiple yaml files each with different base-paths then there is no possibility to provide a base-path for each yaml file in the specmatic.json.
Could you please share if there is a way to inject base-path for each yaml or an alternate solution ?
To run the test on a single yaml, I provide the base-path in --testBaseUrl parameter itself.
However, when the specmatic.json has multiple yaml files each with different base-paths then there is no possibility to provide a base-path for each yaml file

Thanks Akshat. CTO of Specmatic here. This is a great question. Apologies for the delay in response. Currently we do not have a mechanism to use the server URL itself as the "testBaseURL" or specific a "testBaseURL" for each spec file that is listed as a test in specmatic.json. Let me quickly check which of these will be viable for us to support and get back to you.
